# array of image literals getting "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" in swift 5

Tags: swift, model-view-controller

I am new to coding and am trying to learn Swift. I am making a simple "Rock Paper Scissors" app to practice using MVC.

I have an array (let imagesArray = [image literal, image literal, image literal]

when I have images array in the controller it works fine but when I try to move it to the model I get a "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error. Are image arrays not allowed in the model? my understanding is that data should be kept in the model so that's why I am trying to put it in there.

any thoughts would be much appreciated :)

```
struct GameBrain {
    
    let images = [ #imageLiteral(resourceName: "rock"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "paper"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "scissors")]
    
    func playGame() -> Int {
        let choices = [0,1,2]
        let choice = choices.randomElement()
        return choice!
    }
    
    mutating func getWinner(choice: Int?) {
        
    }
}
```

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var gameBrain = GameBrain()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewLeft: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewRight: UIImageView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func goButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        imageViewLeft.image = images[gameBrain.playGame()]
        imageViewRight.image = images[gameBrain.playGame()]
    }
}
```

Comment: Your view controller doesn’t know what `images` is, change it to `gameBrain.images`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move `images` into the model you have to adjust the references

```
@IBAction func goButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    imageViewLeft.image = gameBrain.images[gameBrain.playGame()]
    imageViewRight.image = gameBrain.images[gameBrain.playGame()]
}
```

---

Apparently the index is not needed so this is simpler

```
var playGame : UIImage { 
   return images.randomElement()! 
}
```

and

```
@IBAction func goButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    imageViewLeft.image = gameBrain.playGame
    imageViewRight.image = gameBrain.playGame
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats awesome it's much shorter syntax! it all works except the part of storing the array in the model (i still get the "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error) if I put any other array with a different datatype it doesn't get the error just my images array. Thanks again!

Comment: In which line do you get the error? Actually this code does not cause errors.

Comment: only on the line where the images array is declared in the GameBrain struct, if i move the images to the view controller it works but if I have it in the gamebrain i get that error, very confusing

Comment: Try to replace `#imageLiteral(resourceName` with `UIImage(named:`

Comment: nuts that didn't work either (cannot find "UIImage" in scope) Thank you so much for helping. I guess I will just put the image array in the controller

Comment: If the model is in a separate file you have to `import UIKit`.

Comment: Oh my gosh! thank you! it worked :) as a new developer there is so many things I don't think of naturally yet. Thank you so much!!